# 64: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (No error) (-26)

Tags: raw-transaction

What does this error mean?

I've manually constructed a transaction, and I get this error when I try to insert it in to the network.

Comment: did you solved the problem? I have faced the similar problem when i tried to send some bitcoin to multiple output addresses. when i tried with a single output address it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3038eb63e8a674b4818cb5d5e461f1ccf4b2932f/src/main.cpp#L1415-L1426):

```
// Check whether the failure was caused by a
// non-mandatory script verification check, such as
// non-standard DER encodings or non-null dummy
// arguments; if so, don't trigger DoS protection to
// avoid splitting the network between upgraded and
// non-upgraded nodes.
```

It sounds like maybe your transaction signature isn't standard.

Comment: In this case it's very likely it's BIP62 low-s standardness.